# Is there a command in R that allows you to replace empty cells with a "."?

Tags: r

I have MAF files which contains empty cells and columns. When the file is read it R using `read.table` the contents shift along the row out of their designated cells and into the empty cell. I need to read in the file to use MesKit

I am wondering if there is a way to add in full stops into the empty cells in order to keep the rest of the cells in their desiganted columns?

I have tried reading in the table and then using:

```
df <- maf.File
df <- replace(df, df=='', ".")
```

This did not work.

I have also tried using the replace command while reading in the file which gives me an error:

> Error in !header : invalid argument type

If I add in `header = TRUE` , i get another error:

> Error in scan(file, what = "", sep = sep, quote = quote, nlines = 1, quiet = TRUE,  : invalid 'sep' value: must be one byte

Any help and advice is appreciated.

Comment: Rather than using `read.table`, use `read.delim`. That should fix it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph when using read.delim I get another error:                                                                              Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.